# gcc error generation

Tags: c, variables, memory-management

Why does neither gcc or clang generate an error when I try to compile code containing the following two lines?

```
int palindrome(char s[]){
    char s2[strlen(s)];
```

I thought in such an instance you would have to dynamically allocate memory to s2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC has an extension for this behavior, and it's also standard in C99, known as variable length arrays.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Clang supports it due to GCC C and C99: http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla

Answer (score 2):

Section `6.7.5.2 Array declarators`:

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If
>   the size is `*` instead of
>   being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type
>   of unspecified size,
>   which can only be used in declarations with function prototype
>   scope) such arrays are
>   nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression
>   and the element
>   type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable
>   length array type;
>   otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

And an example from `6.5.3.4`:

> ```
> #include <stddef.h>
> size_t fsize3(int n)
> {
>       char b[n+3];     // variable length array
>       return sizeof b; // execution time sizeof
> }
> ```

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf (not the standard, but a draft, and *free*. :)